# h2o and parquet - can not determine file type error

Tags: python, amazon-s3, parquet, h2o

We are using H2O (latest version 3.22.1.1) to read parquet data from s3. We use python to talk to H2O. This is single H2O instance - not cluster.

Sometimes we get this error:

Server error water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException:
  Error: Cannot determine file type. for s3a://BUCKET_NAME/5c2e3fdc0c9c1800019c73f9/part-00001-c33635a2-76dc-4e49-948b-465726b7e3d9-c000.snappy.parquet

File exists and is valid parquet file. Subsequent imports work fine.

This is our python code to import file into H2O

h2o.import_file(path='s3a://BUCKET_NAME/5c2e3fdc0c9c1800019c73f9/part-00001-c33635a2-76dc-4e49-948b-465726b7e3d9-c000.snappy.parquet')

Is there any way to force h2o to use parquet type?

Comment: Are you using amazon services ??

Comment: yes... parquet is stored in s3 and h2o is running in ec2

Comment: Are you saying that the same exact import_file() call is flakey and sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work?  If so, that sounds like a bug and I would be interested to be able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

H20 Manual says to do it like `df = h2o.import_file("/pathToFile/fileName")`  When 
 you need `to load data from the machine(s) running H2O to the machine running Python`.

So if your server is not running H20 probably that's why it is showing error.

Comment: h2o node is running for sure.. we get exception from it :) - but I am confused why it would not recognize our parquet file to be parquet